# How to transfer files remote to local using SSH

Tags: ssh

What terminal command can I use to transfer a directory from a remote machine (linux) to my local machine (mac)? **Most importantly, I'd like to do this from the command line while SSH'ed into the remote machine.** I know how to use SCP while on my local machine command line, but I have no idea how I'd use it from the remote machine (nor what my local path would be).

Comment: Is your local machine behind a firewall? Is there a particular reason you need to do this while remotely logged in?

Comment: I'm using su to access the files, so didn't think I could do this while not logged in.

Comment: Ah. Well, if you have read access to the files while not root, you should still be able to access them via scp from your local machine. If they're not readable by anyone that isn't root, then yeah, you'd need to run the copy as root.

Comment: Right. So I have to run the copy as root. Seems like SCP still works if I know the full path to my mac, right? How would I find this?

Comment: Well, that goes back to my first question, are you behind a firewall/router, or is your Mac publicly accessible (if you're at home, are you directly plugged into your modem?)?

Comment: I'm behind a router. So when I enable remote access it just shows me the local IP (e.g. To log in to this computer remotely, type "ssh username@192.168.1.102").

Comment: Do you own the router/can you configure it? If so, you can configure it to forward a port to your local machine. SSH runs on port 22, but I generally recommend avoiding opening standard ports on home machines. In your NAT configuration, you should be able to map something like 22000 externally to 22 locally. Of course, you can still open 22. You'd need to [find your external IP](http://www.whatismyip.org/) and use that instead of your 192 address.

Comment: Perfect, you are exactly right. Feel free to write up in an answer and I'll choose it. Thanks!

Comment: If you have the credentials to SSH into the machine, and read access to the files, you could use `rsync` very easily - there are enough tutorials online to help you out. Its great for resuming downloads and checking for corruption, etc. Also has a nice progress bar if you use --progress. You probably would have used it already if you could (since its fairly popular), but its something to bare in mind that is very useful for even other things like remote backups, file transfer, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start the `sshd` on your local computer if you hadn't already done this. Then start a *second* session from your local computer to the remote computer:

```
ssh -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 user@remote
```

This forwards the remote port 2222 to the `sshd` listening on 127.0.0.1 on your local computer, creating a `reverse tunnel`. Then run `scp` on the remote computer:

```
scp -P2222 file 127.0.0.1:/path/
```

Comment: I did not know that. Much simpler!

Comment: Wow cool. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the opposite, to grab a file from a remote machine to the local machine,

```
ssh -L 2222:user@192.168.1.37:22 user@remoteserver.com -N &
scp -P 2222 127.0.0.1:/path/to/file/on/remote/machine.diff /tmp
```

The ssh command sets up a tunnel from localhost:2222 to the remote machine 192.168.1.37 behind the net facing server remoteserver.com.  The second command lets you copy it locally.

Some [good examples and tips here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example), and how to configure it in ~/.ssh/config to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're locally behind a router/firewall that is giving you a private IP address, you'll need to configure the router to NAT a port to map to your local port 22. You can then access it from the remote computer by addressing your [public IP address](http://www.whatismyip.org/) on whatever port you choose (you can map port 22 directly, but I generally personally recommend avoiding this as standard server ports are common targets for malware trying to find a way in).

Comment: That won't be necessary.

Comment: One other note: make sure that Remote Login is enabled via System Preferences if on a mac.